# How to run Facebook Infer on Windows

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-infer

I know the official docs mentioned only Mac and Linux options, but I tried on Cygwin with the Android example. 
Always get the following error: 
`C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Users/Tung/infer-linux64-v0.1.0/infer/infer/bin/infer':`

Am I missing anything? Has anyone been successful on this? Thanks

Comment: Actually I will be very interested if there is a windows binary to try infer.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Infer currently [doesn't support Windows](http://fbinfer.com/support.html#faq). We recommend trying Infer on Windows using a Linux virtual machine, if your project also compiles on Linux.

Comment: Are you affiliated with Infer?

Comment: @RobertColumbia According to his website "I am a Software Engineer in the Static Analysis Tools team at Meta in London" so probably the answer is yes